# Choosing a group action to do GIT of hypersurfaces

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, moduli-spaces, hilbert-schemes, geometric-invariant-theory, stability

When studying GIT stability of hypersurfaces $d$ of $\mathbb P^n$ we look at the Hilbert Scheme $H=\mathbb P^N$ parametrizing homogeneous polynomials $f_d(x_0,\ldots,x_n)$ of degree $d$. There is normally a group $G$ acting on $\mathbb P^n$ which induces an action on $H$.

The GIT compactification is then $H^{ss}//G$ where we have restricted to semistable surfaces.

A natural option for $G$ would be to take $G=\mathrm{Aut}(\mathbb P^n)=PGL(n+1)$ so that we identify two hypersurfaces if they are related by an automorphism of $\mathbb P^n$. However in a few sources I have consulted this is never the case. Indeed, they always use either

- $G=GL(n+1)$ (e.g. Mukai's "An Introduction to Invariants and Moduli" in the study of cubic surfaces)
- $G=SL(n+1)$ (e.g. Alcock's "The Moduli Space of Cubic Threefolds")

**Q1**: Why is $PGL(n+1)$ never used?

I understand that any group used must include $SL(n+1)$ in order to apply Hilbert-Mumford's numerical criterion. So my second question is:

**Q2**: How to decide if choosing GL or SL? Doesn't using SL imply that we are considering two isomorphic hypersurfaces to be different when taking quotient?

**Q3** I understand (see comments) that $SL$ gives a unique linearization of the line bundle, but shouldn't $PGL$ be used in all cases when constructing compactifications of the moduli of hypersurfaces given that it is what determines if two hypersurfaces are isomorphic by isomorphisms of $\mathbb P^n$?

Comment: Although there exists an action of $\textbf{PGL}_{n+1}$ on $\mathbb{P}k[x_0,\dots,x_n]_d$ for every $d$, this only lifts to a linear action on the vector space $k[x_0,\dots,x_n]$ if $n+1$ divides $d$.

Comment: Thank you Jason, that explains Mukai's choice. Do you have a reference for that statement? (Or an idea of where to look for one)

Comment: In Chapter 7 of Dolgachev's "Lectures on Invariant Theory", he describes the obstruction to linearizing a given action.

Comment: The group $PGL_{N+1}$ is used in http://www-irma.u-strasbg.fr/~benoist/articles/Thesefinale.pdf and http://arxiv.org/abs/1505.02249

Comment: Ariyan is correct.  Even in those cases where $\textbf{PGL}_{n+1}$ does not linearize to $\mathcal{O}(1)$ on $\mathbb{P}k[x_0,\dots,x_n]_d$, it does linearize some positive tensor power, e.g., $\mathcal{O}(n)$.  So that is not, by itself, a reason one must use $\textbf{SL}_{n+1}$ rather than $\textbf{PGL}_{n+1}$.

Comment: @JasonStarr Thanks for the comments. After reading Dolgachev I don't understand why many authors use $SL_{n+1}$ rather than $PGL_{n+1}$.
e.g, Laza [here](http://arxiv.org/pdf/0704.3256v2.pdf) also uses SL to compactify the moduli of cubic fourfolds. Dolgachev in "Lectures on Invariant Theory", Chapter 10, uses $SL_{n+1}$ to construct compactifications of the moduli of hypersurfaces. I understand SL gives a unique linearization. In particular, in the case of cubic surfaces he uses $SL_{4}$ and gets the same result as Mukai, who uses $GL_4$. Why both groups give the same compactification?

Comment: @AriyanJavanpeykar I cannot notify two people in one comment, but the comment to Jason was for you too ;-)

Comment: @John: Not every linear representation of $\textbf{SL}_{n+1}$ factors through $\textbf{PGL}_{n+1}$.  Thus, for an action of $\textbf{PGL}_{n+1}$ on $X$, for the induced action of $\textbf{SL}_{n+1}$, a $\textbf{SL}_{n+1}$-linearized ample invertible sheaf $\mathcal{O}(1)$ may not factor through a $\textbf{PGL}_{n+1}$-linearization.  Abstractly, we could just pass from $\mathcal{O}(1)$ to $\mathcal{O}(n+1)$.  However, this is analogous to passing from the ideal of a projective variety to the ideal of its Veronese image, already nontrivial for projective space.